# Cannot access nodejs app on browser at localhost:4200 (docker run -p 4200:4200 ....)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, angular-cli, dockerfile, docker-machine

Please I need some help, new to docker; have a feeling it's something minor I missed.

I'm trying to run a nodejs app using a dockerfile and docker-compose; I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 LTS however, eventhough the status shows UP and runnning I can't access the app from ***localhost:4200***

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
 my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

***docker ps***

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
e6a99aab4e37        my-app   "ng serve"               10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp    my-app_1
```

I ran the following command and got an ip address, I used that ip:port# in browser but app won't show up:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 'my-app_1'
```

when I go to localhost:4200 it doesn't work; 
I also tried: `docker run --rm -it -p 4200:4200 my_app_container` and it runs and I can see that npm start runs and listens on port 4200 but when I go to browser and type `localhost:4200` I get nothing, just: this site can't be reached; ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

```
  ubuntu17@ubuntu:~/playground/apps/my_app-ui$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my_app   latest              d41d3d77811b        17 minutes ago      1.24GB
nept0                 latest              df93134e2539        21 minutes ago      1.24GB
node                  9                   c888d933885c        5 days ago          676MB
registry              2.6.1               c2a449c9f834        6 months ago        33.2MB
ubuntu17@ubuntu:~/playground/apps/my_app-ui$ docker run -it --rm -p 4200:4200 nept0
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-01-16T15:46:19.502Z                                                          
Hash: 00ec980debaf8e47350d
Time: 12386ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 270 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 549 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 511 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 11.8 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

LASTLY:
    - The weirdest thing is if I don't use docker and just build the app manually by simply running: `ng serve or npm serve` which looks into `package.json` -> script section and starts ng serve, then `localhost:4200` runs fine so I'm lost at to 1.

Why I can't access `localhost:4200` or `ipaddress:4200` on browser when running via docker but it works if I build manually outside of docker by just running npm start?

Comment: Here's the solution to this problem in case someone else gets stuck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286174/2663059

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286174/2663059

Has the solution.

**EDIT**

First of all . Why you have done this .

```
#EXPOSE 4200
```

in Dockerfile.  # in front means comment in dockerfile . Use this

```
 EXPOSE 4200
```

`#EXPOSE 4200 means you have not expose the port .`

And next check that container running your node server inside the Docker or not.
How can you check is this.
    docker exec -it nept0 bash
or can try

```
docker exec -it nept0 /bin/bash
```

Then you can run

curl localhost:4200  **or** the get api of the node.js if that working fine your node is working fine #EXPOSE 4200 was culprit .

You can read for docker exec here more https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Let me know if any issue.

Comment: Thanks you for helping me; I commented out the EXPOSE because I'm mounting the port in my docker-compose.yml file, do I have to expose in both places i.e in the dockerfile and also in the docker-compose file? I thought I could just mount the port from docker-compose and be fine? But let me try uncommenting and see what happens

Comment: NO issue . Check out and Let me know if any issue , not a big deal.

Comment: The issue was this: I needed to do: ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve", "-H", "0.0.0.0"] instead of ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve"] to tell docker to listen to bind to all interfaces in my docker container: here's where I got the solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286174/2663059 - Hope this helps someone

Comment: Cool :) . That nice